# How can i get actor position when they are moved

Tags: pawn

I try to AI using actor not NPC!

because NPC has may many using resource so, finally i found actor

even though actor move using actor anim, they position are static not changing.

i used to but only GetActorPos but also GetDynamicActorPos,
reseult are same as above.

how can i get actor position when they are moved using anim?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's SA-MP you are asking about, it is not possible to automatically derive the new position. Only the client is aware of what the animation looks like and where the actor's position actually is in the world, and there is no way to retrieve that information from the server. You'll basically have to guess where the new position should be, based on the time elapsed since the animation started.